# Stripe @ missing param success_url , even if it is exists

Tags: php, stripe-payments

trying to understand, why i'm getting error (developer took money and gone)

I'm trying to buy a stuff, and once I click BUY, I receive this error `Missing required param: success_url.`

I'm using Laravel.

but in code, I can see that, success_url exists.

```
 \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(Setting::get('stripe_secret_key'));
    $session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create(
        [
            'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
            'line_items' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'Test',
                    'description' => 'Test2: '.implode(', ', $vouchersNames),
                    'amount' => $total * 100,
                    'currency' => 'eur',
                    'quantity' => 1,
                ],
            ],
            'success_url' => env('APP_URL').'buy_vouchers_done?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}&vouchers='.urlencode(implode(',', $vouchers->pluck('id')->toArray())),
            'cancel_url' => env('APP_URL'),
        ]);
```

Where is a problem? Thank you!

Comment: Most likely `env('APP_URL') doesn't contain what you think it does; I'd recommend logging its content and seeing what it contains.

Comment: it contain my app url.. ghmm

Comment: The error says you're not sending that parameter to Stripe, so this is something you have to debug in your code to understand why.